# Laravel 5.1 Database session keeps regenerating every request

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

So the issue is that on every request a new session is created and stored in the database so `Sessions` are storing themselves in the `sessions table` but its like Laravel just ignores them and creates a new one every request.

I have removed `whitespace` like some people suggested. This all happened when I upgraded to Laravel 5.1

FYI: The file session driver works.

If anyone has encountered this, how did you resolve it?

Cheers

Comment: how did you configure config/session.php ?

Comment: what did you end up doing?